# In chrome, how to view and print webpage in a cellphone aspect ratio on a PC?

Tags: google-chrome

I have some bar codes that I need to print from chrome on a PC, except the webpage was desgined for a standard cellphone screen size.

In chrome, How to print this screen to an exact cellphone sized screen on paper?  I don't want it stretched, but exactly the same pixels sizes of an iphone screen when printing from chrome.

Alternatively, let's say I save the image of the webpage and get a bitmap file with the exact dimensions of an IPHONE.... how to print from a graphics windows program to get the exact size of an iphone when printed?

Comment: I think that the problem should be solved by the web page designer including a correct print style sheet. Also this probably not on topic for ServerFault. In worst case, create screenshots as I did below and print those without scaling. Note that generally using a print function from a cell phone also won't print the exact cellphone screen ...

Answer (score 1):

For viewing : Chrome developer tools has a [Device Mode](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/) setting:

[image: Device mode preview]